# java convert binary/ocal/hex double values

Tags: java, binary, hex, octal

I have a double value in binary/octal/hex format and would like to convert them between each other. I was able to do it with integer values like this

```
  Long l = Long.valueOf(value, FORMAT_FROM); //FORMAT_FROM -> 2 || 8 || 16
  //and then 
  Long.toHexString(l) //or
  Long.toBinaryString(l) //or
  Long.toOctalString(l)
```

The decimal value `11.13` should be (checked this with a calculator):

```
  13.102436561   //Octal
  1011.001000011 //Binary
  B.2147AE148  //Hex
```

Any idea or hint how to get there?

Answer (score 0):

`Long` is simply a 64-bit signed **integer** and does not accept fractional values. Do the same thing except with `Double`:

```
  Double d = Double.valueOf(value, FORMAT_FROM); //FORMAT_FROM -> 2 || 8 || 16
  //and then 
  Double.toHexString(d) //or
```

Sadly binary and octal are not directly available.

Comment: `Double.toBinaryString` and `Double.toOctalString` don't exist!?

Comment: @wasp256 What about those two methods?

Comment: It says `Cannot resolve method `toBinaryString(java.lang.double)`

Comment: @wasp256 Sadly `Double` only offers `toHexString`, is there any reason you need the binary and octal?

Comment: t know that it offers only that one thats why I'm lost and ask the question on SO